# Sitemap indexing

Tags: search-engine-indexing, sitemap

I recently started working for e-commerce website and I noticed their website was missing a Sitemap. They sell more than 10 million titles and google indexed only 200 pages when I checked in google search console. So to start the things I uploaded a sitemap with 48k files and waiting for google to crawl and index them. I have submitted a validation request but nothing changed. It just crawled 30 URL's till now. Can anyone suggest how shall I approach this please. Shall I scale down the URL'S to less than 10k and build gradually or upload all product listings? How frequently can I update the sitemap in this scenario.

Comment: There are several similar questions with the answers here, as  https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5560/sitemaps-index-submission and  https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18243/can-a-sitemap-index-contain-other-sitemap-indexes